# One doubt in the proof of inverse function theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

What I want to show is following. If f analytic at $z_{0}$ and $f'(z_{0})$ is not zero then there is neighborhood around this point where function is one one. Actually I am going through proof of inverse function theorem by one professor ( you tube video) . So to prove this theorem he has first proved the above fact that I have mentioned. The idea he has used goes like this.

Say $f(z_{0})=w_{0}$. Then since f is analytic $f-w_{0}$ is analytic and since zeros of analytic function are isolated we can find r such that inside disc $|z-z_{0}| \leq r$ there are no other zeros of $f-w_{0}$ other than $z_{0}$. Now ( by same argument which is used to prove open mapping theorem by defining N(w)= number of times function assumes value w....this argument I also found in T. gamelin) we can find $\delta$ such that for all w inside disc $|w-w_{0}|<\delta$, there is exactly one z in disc $|z-z_{0}| < r$ such that f(z)=w. Everything was good till here but then lecturer said that this means f is one one in disc $|z-z_{0}| < r$. But what is the guarantee that inverse of whole disc$|w-w_{0}|<\delta$ is  $|z-z_{0}| < r$ . I am also confused at one more point. I have understood proof of whole theorem but see we want to construct neighborhood around $z_{0}$ and to define inverse function professor has used same disc in w plane as above but my doubt is" I know if f is continuous then inverse image of open set is open but how to show that inverse of that open neighborhood around $w_{0}$ is actually again some neighborhood around $z_{0} $?

Comment: Another (maybe better) idea: use the *real*  inverse function theorem. Also, you can check that the (local) inverse function verifies the Cauchy-Riemann equations, so...

Comment: But I really want to understand proof by this way. Can someone please help about this. How to get neighborhood around $z_{0}$. Or some hint. Thanks

Comment: @Martin-Blas Perez Pinilla is there proof available online by the method I have mentioned.

Comment: The image of $|z-z_0| <r$ is open, and $w_0$ is an interior point of the image set. Being an interior point, it comes with a $\delta >0$ such that $|w-w_0| < \delta$ is completely contained in the image of $|z-z_0|<r$. So there is no doubt that for each $w$ there is a $z$ in $B(z_0, r)$. I guess you are thinking that the professor claimed $f(B(z_0, r))=B(w_0, \delta)$.

Comment: @Skylark but then how will I get neighborhood around $z_{0}$ in which function is one one?